# Risks for VBAC vs repeat Cesarean

Tags: risks, birth, c-section, vaginal-delivery, obstetrics

When discussing a possible vaginal birth after cesarean (VBAC), healthcare professionals often cite the risk of uterine rupture during VBAC as a motivation for repeat Cesarean.  This is however only one of multiple risks associated with either procedure.

Taking all risks into account, what is the combined risk of death or serious injury for a repeat cesarean (for completeness sake, only second cs) as compared to a VBAC (VBA1C), for an otherwise uncomplicated pregnancy (e.g. no pre-eclampsia, diabetes, etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You have asked a couple of questions about vbac risks, is this something you have addressed with an ob-gyn?

Comment: Yes. Not everything the obgyn says makes sense, which is why I'm trying to track down research based facts from, hopefully, a neutral community. I'm afraid of pro-vbac sites (of which there are a few) downplaying the risks.

Answer (score 6):

This question is difficult to answer because risk discussions are individualized.  Instead of answering, I will point you to reliable resources to guide your discussion with your OB.

One great source of pooled evidence is UpToDate. I would also recommend reading articles from ACOG and AAFP, professional organizations that are going to be impartial as opposed to agenda-driven topical websites.

BUT the ultimate risks/benefits discussion and ultimate decision MUST be held between you and your provider. We cannot provide that for you.

I would recommend reading up through reputable websites like these, then taking the information and your questions to your OB GYN and tell them you are having trouble understanding.  If they are unable to explain something like that to you, perhaps it is best for you to find a different OB GYN who can connect better with you.

- [UpToDate VBAC](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/vaginal-birth-after-cesarean-delivery-vbac-beyond-the-basics#H3)
- [ACOG VBAC](https://www.acog.org/Womens-Health/Vaginal-Birth-After-Cesarean-VBAC?IsMobileSet=false)
- [AAFP VBAC](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2015/0201/p197.html)

Comment: Yes, I second that: your risk of VBAC depends on details of your prior cesarean, your uterus, and your baby. Don't be afraid to ask about this. A good obstetrician will be happy to discuss this with you, you just have to be clear and direct that you want more than the standard spiel.